# Runtime error SIGSEGV on SPOJ ACPC10D

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was solving ACPC10D problem from spoj [LINK](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACPC10D/) but I am constantly getting RTE SIGSEGV while submitting. I have tried all the testcases which are mentioned in the forum and my solution gives correct output to every testcase.

The people in the forum commented that it is not possible to solve it with top down approach. Howeever it is simple dp problem and my solution seems to be correct.

Following is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int rows;
typedef long long ll;
ll dp[5][100005];
ll cost[5][100005];
ll func(int i,int j)
{
    if(i<1 || i>rows || j<1 || j>3)
        return 100000000;
    if(i==rows && j==2)
        return cost[i][j];
        if(i==rows && j==3)
            return 100000000;
            if(i==rows && j==1)
                return cost[i][j]+cost[i][j+1];
            if(dp[i][j]!=0)
                return dp[i][j];
    ll answer=100000000;
    if(j==1)
    {
        answer=min(answer,func(i,j+1));
        answer=min(answer,func(i+1,j));
        answer=min(answer,func(i+1,j+1));
        return dp[i][j]=cost[i][j]+answer;
    }
    if(j==2)
    {
        answer=min(answer,func(i,j+1));
        answer=min(answer,func(i+1,j));
        answer=min(answer,func(i+1,j+1));
        answer=min(answer,func(i+1,j-1));
        return dp[i][j]=cost[i][j]+answer;
    }
    if(j==3)
    {
        answer=min(answer,func(i+1,j));
        answer=min(answer,func(i+1,j-1));
        return dp[i][j]=cost[i][j]+answer;
    }
}
int main()
{
    for(int i=1;;i++)
    {
        cin >>  rows;
        if(rows==0)
            break;
        memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
        memset(cost,100000000,sizeof(cost));
        for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
            {
                cin >> cost[i][j];
            }
        }
        ll answer=func(1,2);
        cout << i << ". ";
        cout << answer << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You access your arrays as `dp[row][col]`, but their definition is the other way round. You also have two nested loops that each define a variable called `i` in `main`. `memset(cost, 100000000, sizeof(cost))` doesn't do what you think it does; since you use C++, consider using `std::fill` instead.

Comment: What is the difference between memset and fill?

Comment: `memset` is the old, type-ignorant C way of setting individual _bytes_. The value to assign is treated as an unsigned char. You assign 100,000,000 or `0x5f5e100`, of which only the `0x00` survive. You effectively set all weights to zero. `std::fill` is a template that knows about the type of the vector and sets each element properly. Try it out.